# Update Workflow Instances using DynamicUpdateServices

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

What is the right process to follow to ensure that long running workflow instances can be upgraded to new workflow definition in the future.

I know that I have to call `DynamicUpdateServices.PrepareForUpdate` against my existing XAML before I proceed to do any new changes so I can later call `DynamicUpdateServices.CreateUpdateMap` and generate the mapping file that I will use to upgrade existing Workflow instances.

What isn't really clear to me is which workflow definition (XAML) file should you modify after calling `DynamicUpdateServices.PrepareForUpdate`. Is it the (cloned) XAML file that was created after calling `DynamicUpdateServices.PrepareForUpdate`. Or the original XAML file?

It seems that the cloned XAML file should be the obvious choice, but there's a problem. The cloned XAML file doesn't contain the `ViewStateManager` tag which means you loose all the layouts that you have in the original XAML.

On the other hand, if I use the original XAML then how should I generate the Update Map?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted MS Support and finally understand how it works.

I never really have to touch the cloned definition. The key concept that I previously didn't understand is that the `DynamicUpdateServices.PrepareForUpdate()` intent is not really to prepare the XAML file, but rather prepare the WF runtime itself so it can generate the update map by comparing the modified XAML against the cloned copy that was generated (and stored in the memory when the `DynamicUpdateServices.PrepareForUpdate()`) was called.So a typical process would be:

1. Deploy workflow definition (`v1 xaml`)
2. Modify the workflow definition (`v2 xaml`)
3. Deploy workflow definition (`v2 xaml`) * can also be done after step 5 instead
4. Call `DynamicUpdateServices.PrepareForUpdate()` against `v1 xaml` (get from source control)
5. Generate Update map `DynamicUpdateServices.CreateUpdateMap()`
6. Apply the update map to existing workflow instances that was persisted and started from `v1 xaml` (`WorkflowApplication.Load(instance, updateMap)`)

Step 4 and 5 must be done in the same process instance (or in most cases it just means in the same host).

Comment: I tried your solution, but it is not working for me. since I don't understand how step 4 and 5 are executed, and how your xaml v1 and v2 are co-related, since prepareForUpdate and CreateMap should use same activty object or Xaml for that matter.. otherwise createMap method fails.

Comment: @KhurramShakir. Yes, this seems to be a very complicated process. I suggest you check out this blog. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlos/archive/2013/11/29/dynamic-update-in-wf4-5-sample-using-a-re-hosted-workflow-designer.aspx It discussed about a rehosted workflow designer approach which may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am looking for the article and it seems interesting... Based on similarity of our initial scenarios, let me explain what I am currently doing, and you might give me some other helpful advise for that, [Initially I posted that as a response of your answer, but deleted by moderator.]

Comment: My Scenario is as follows, I created a workflow update utility,

1. I take Base Xaml File Name and Assembly (V1) from User.
2. I prepare a updated Map of it and save it as updated Xaml.
3. I load that updated Xaml File in project ,and modify the workflow.
4. After modification and rebuilding, I again open my update utility and take input from User the modified Xaml (v2) and Create update map.
5. But when I tried to update the running instance, although they are updated but at run time make undesirable effects , related to Expression parsing, Root , etc.
Any other comments about it ??

Comment: I suggest you open up a new question and describe it in detail. Like what are those undesirable effects exactly, error messages, etc.